# I want to calculate the size of the bitcoin block

Tags: java, bitcoin

I want to calculate the size of the bitcoin block
And I saw the subject: [link here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41196/how-is-the-size-of-a-block-calculated),
and in one response someone says "merkle root hash - 32 bytes"

Then I went to this block: [link here](https://blockchain.info/rawblock/0000000000000000001416bc09d94b22d00ace967832c7fa9dd67df60d0d1612)

merkle root is: 8f5318a45316efedf56ebcadd55889ab377ba78d9a8ac14a81a83e52ad45e07f

i tried to calculate the root, but it appeared with me that it was 64 bytes.

my way of calculating bytes:

```
byte[] bytes1 = "Here merkle root".getBytes();

System.out.println(bytes1.length);
```

Result 64 rather than 32

Comment: You're comparing something that's base64 encoded with your expectation that it's that much in raw form.

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me

Comment: `8f5318...` is not the actual value it's a [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of the value.

Comment: OK
I tried to return the text to its original state
But the length 84, code is so:      byte[] decodedBytes= Base64.decodeBase64("8f5318a45316efedf56ebcadd55889ab377ba78d9a8ac14a81a83e52ad45e07f".getBytes());
String str =new String(decodedBytes);

System.out.println(str.length());

Comment: @tadman I'd think it is hex-encoded, not base64.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's probably a better idea as that would be 2x the size.

Answer (score 1):

The merkle root is 32 bytes, presented with hex encoding (using 0-9a-z). That means that two characters will be used to represent each byte and the result string will have twice as many characters as the original data has bytes.

You can not convert a string to bytes by doing `getBytes()` as that gets the bytes representing the string.

You can parse the string into either a number (a big number) with BigInteger or into a byte array manually or using external library (not included in the JDK).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String merkle = "8f5318a45316efedf56ebcadd55889ab377ba78d9a8ac14a81a83e52ad45e07f";
    System.out.println("String length: " + merkle.length());
    System.out.println("Actual decimal value: " + new BigInteger(merkle, 16));

    byte[] bytes = toBytes(merkle);
    System.out.println("Total bytes: " + bytes.length);
    System.out.println("Actual bytes: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
}

private static byte[] toBytes(String input) {
    byte[] result = new byte[input.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (byte)((Character.digit(input.charAt(i * 2), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(input.charAt(i * 2 + 1), 16));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` does hex and is in JRE since 6 at least.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Didn't think of looking there (normally use external libraries). Will update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer